# how can I set a id without it being string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

i have a collection called "User", this collection has a "address" field that contains a array of objects
Objective:Recieve the adress object id, edit it with received data, update the database
My code:

```
async updateAdress(input) {
        const { idUser, idAdress, adressInfo } = input;
        let user = await User.findById(idUser);
        let counter = 0;

        console.log(adressInfo);
        let old = user.adressInfo;
        user.adressInfo.forEach(adress => {

            if (adress.id == idAdress) {
                old[counter] = adressInfo;

            }
            counter++;
        });
        console.log(old);
        return User.findByIdAndUpdate(idUser, { $set: { adressInfo: old } }, { new: true }).catch(
            err => console.error(err)
        );
    },
```

Problem: it does edit the array of objects and the console just shows what I wanted to happen(I thought), but in the database, it set the object I edited fields to null and update to a different id, so I assume the problem is in not setting the id when I edit the object, so I tried to add the id on GraphQL query and even using " adressInfo._id=idAdress", but the error keeps appearing, and I assume its because the _id field is now a string instead of a normal MongoDB id, so how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use [array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/index.html) to modify and update array fields within a document.

Comment: I found a solution , added the fields individually, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I will let it here to eventual problems like mine

```
async updateAdress(input) {
    const { idUser, idAdress, adressInfo } = input;
    let user = await User.findById(idUser);
    let counter = 0;


    let old = user.adressInfo;
    console.log(adressInfo[0].adress);
    user.adressInfo.forEach(adress => {

        if (adress.id == idAdress) {
            old[counter]['adress'] = adressInfo[0].adress;
            old[counter]['adress2'] = adressInfo[0].adress2;
            old[counter]['postalCode'] = adressInfo[0].postalCode;
            old[counter]['city'] = adressInfo[0].city;
            old[counter]['area'] = adressInfo[0].area;

        }
        counter++;
    });
    console.log(old);
    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(idUser, { $set: { adressInfo: old } }, { new: true }).catch(
        err => console.error(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: there should be a single `adressInfo` arg, not array ... and you can use 1-liner `old[counter] = ...adressInfo;` ... or better, 10x shorter, use `.map()` - return new `addressInfo` for matching id or existing element